# Django Migration Fails Custom Field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am attempting to bring a project on Python 2.4/ Django 1.2 up to date.

The project previously worked until the update. When running python manage.py migrate

I get:

```
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File manage.py, line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py, line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py, line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py, line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py, line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py, line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get(fake, False))
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py, line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py, line 91, in apply_migration
    if self.detect_soft_applied(migration):
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py, line 135, in detect_soft_applied
    apps = project_state.render()
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py, line 54, in render
    real_models.append(ModelState.from_model(model, exclude_rels=True))
  File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py, line 182, in from_model
    e,
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field map_type on core.AffiliateMap: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Sample Code which I believe is the issue (commenting out the EnumerationField in Company stops the error):

```
class Company(models.Model):
   CATEGORIES = ['Unspecified'] + settings.SMS_COMPANY_CATEGORIES
   category = EnumerationField(enum=CATEGORIES, default=CATEGORIES[0])

class EnumerationField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField):
   __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

   def __init__(self, enum, *args, **kwargs):
      self.enum = enum
      self.enum_dict = dict(zip(enum, range(len(enum))))
      kwargs['choices'] = [(v, v) for v in enum]
      if 'default' in kwargs:
         value = kwargs['default']
         if value in enum:
            kwargs['default'] = self.enum_dict[value]
         else:
            raise ValueError(No %s value in enumeration % value)
      print args = %snkwargs = %s % (args, kwargs)
      sys.stdout.flush()
      models.PositiveSmallIntegerField.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

   def to_python(self, value):
      if type(value) is int:
         if not value in range(len(self.enum)):
            raise IndexError('Index %s out of range in enumeration' % value)
         return self.enum[value]
      else:
         if not value:
            return ''
         if not value in self.enum:
            raise ValueError(No %s value in enumeration % value)
         return value

   def get_prep_value(self, value):
      if value in self.enum:
         return self.enum_dict[value]
      else:
         raise ValueError(No %s value in enumeration % value)

   def get_prep_lookup(self, lookupType, value):
      if lookupType == 'exact':
         return self.get_prep_value(value)
      elif lookupType == 'in':
         return [self.get_prep_value(v) for v in value]
      else:
         raise TypeError('Lookup type %s not supported' % lookupType
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest , for update the database of a Prepared project first search one of the names of its current field and see that where exist that field (what files) like `models` ,`forms` and even `__init__` files and ... then define your new field there ! you can search with `grep` in linux :

`grep -E -r "your_field_name or pattern"`

`-E` is for use regular expression patterns !